# Flutter - Type 'Null' is not a sub type of string

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I'm trying to use Firebase to login, but I'm getting *Type 'Null' is not a sub type of string* as error when I try to parse `_userId = responseData['localId'];`

When I try to parse `_token = responseData['idToken'];`, it works correctly.

`responseData['localId']` is not NULL.

Here is full code:

```
class Auth with ChangeNotifier {
String? _token;
String? _userId;

Future<void> _authenticate(
  String email, String password, String urlSegment) async {
  var url = Uri.parse(
    'https://www.google.com');
  var body = json.encode({
  'email': email,
  'password': password,
  'returnSecureToken': true,
 });
 try {
   final response = await http.post(url, body: body);
   final responseData = json.decode(response.body);
   _token = responseData['idToken'];
   _userId = responseData['localId'];
   } catch (err) {
     throw err;
   }
}

  Future<void> login(String email, String password) async {
    return _authenticate(email, password, 'signInWithPassword');
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the output of `print(response.body);`?

Comment: {
  "kind": "identitytoolkit#VerifyPasswordResponse",
  "localId": "q2oyit2Tf6aUkM0dO9huZlPyx9H3",
  "email": "test@test.com",
  "displayName": "",
  "idToken": "eyJhbGciOiJSUz",
  "registered": true,
  "refreshToken": "AFxQ4_rv1LlH2A",
  "expiresIn": "3600"
}

Comment: Can you please add the entire error message?

Comment: _TypeError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String')

Comment: I think your error is caused by something else. Can you try, for the sake of it, to remove the `try { } catch()` block and paste the entire error message (including offending line etc)